# How to create an instance for a given Type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, constructor

With generics you can

```
var object = default(T);
```

But when all you have is a Type instance I could only

```
constructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
var parameters = new object[0];
var obj = constructor.Invoke(parameters);
```

or even

```
var obj = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[0]);
```

Isn't there a shorter way, like the generics version?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The closest available is [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

... but of course this relies on there being a public parameterless constructor. (Other overloads allow you to specify constructor arguments.)

I've used an explicitly typed variable here to make it clear that we really don't have a variable of the type itself... you can't write:

```
Type t = typeof(MemoryStream);
// Won't compile
MemoryStream ms = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

for example. The compile-time type of the return value of `CreateInstance` is always `object`.

Note that `default(T)` *won't* create an instance of a reference type - it gives the default value for the type, which is a null reference for reference types. Compare that with `CreateInstance` which would actually create a new object.

Comment: Why wouldn't you not mention `Activator.CreateInstanc<T>()` ?

Comment: @nawfal: Because the OP doesn't know `T` - only a `Type` (as an execution-time value).

Comment: Jon yes, the last line of the question confused me.

Answer (score 18):

`var myObject =  Activator.CreateInstance(myType)`

You have to cast if you want to use a typed parameter:

```
User user = (User)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(User));
```

.. or with parameters

```
User user = (User)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(User), new object[]{firstName, lastName});
```

You can also use generics:

```
public T Create<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return new T();
}

var user = Create<User>();
```

Comment: +1 for the second approach. I really like this one :)

Comment: If the type is known at compile time, then you might as well use Activator.CreateInstance<T>().

Comment: why restrict to classes? *:)*

Comment: @nawfal: Value objects are for unicorns.

Comment: If I already know the Type User, why shouldn't I use the new method directly, the question is how to create object elegantly only with the  System.Type variable