# Get a new object instance from a Type and access it as such at compile-time

Tags: c#

Now, before you all rush in to tell me that question has been answered elsewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752/get-a-new-object-instance-from-a-type), for example or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622519/how-to-create-an-instance-for-a-given-type), let me say it's only been partially answered, at least as far as I can see.

I have a variable of type `Type` and I want to create an instance of the type that `t` represents, so I call something like...

```
var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

However, `inst` is on `object` and I want it to be of type `t`. None of the following are legal:

```
t inst = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var inst = (t)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as t;
```

How do I do this? How do I get `inst` to be the type that I want at compile-time?

Comment: " How do I get inst to be the type that I want at compile-time?" - for what purpose? what are you actually trying *to do* with this? if you tell us what you are trying to achieve, I suspect we can advise on an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I need to be able to pass `inst` as a typed parameter to another method.

Comment: a single method? or a series of overloads with different typed parameters? if it is a single method: just cast it - `Foo(123, "abc", (SomeType)inst);`; if it is series of overloads: `dynamic` might help - but is a hack

Comment: Essentially, it would be one of a number of different methods based on the type itself.

Comment: then either *reflection* (manually select and invoke the method), or `dynamic`. The latter is basically an automated way of doing the former. `Foo(123, "abc", (dynamic)inst);` will call the most appropriate method it can find (or error if it can't find an appropriate one)

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks. I'll go and do some research in to `dynamic`.

Comment: @MarcGravell, if you want to copy your question as an answer I'll accept it as such.

Comment: edited (with more detail and context, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That simply isn't possible. The compiler is **static typed** (except for when it isn't ;p). `t` is a *variable*. *variable* != *static*. What you want to do isn't possible.

One option here is *generics*, but that still gets it you as a `<T>`, which doesn't help any if `<T>` still only knows about the same methods as `object`. Another option is `dynamic`; that means `inst.Foo();` will *work* - but only at runtime, and only if the type really does have a `Foo()` method; importantly, the compiler *still* won't know about `t`'s methods at compile-time.

---

From the comments, it seems that the intended usage here is for method overload resolution; `dynamic` can help with that - for example:

```
Foo(Customer cust) {...}
Foo(Order order) {...}
Foo(Region region) {...}

object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // t probably one of the above types
...
Foo((dynamic)inst);
```

will try to invoke the *most appropriate* `Foo` overload based on the *runtime* type of `inst`, with per-type cache optimizations etc. It is a bit of a hack, *but it works*, and is easier and cleaner than checking manually (and thanks to the strategy cache, often more efficient too).

If the *only* thing you are doing with `inst` is passing it onwards, you could make `inst` itself `dynamic`:

```
dynamic inst = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Foo(inst);
```

Note that you should *generally* be a little cautious of this, however, as once a variable is `dynamic`, *all* access to it is via the `dynamic` API - even a call to a method that takes an `object` parameter (such as `string.Format`) would be routed via the runtime rather than the compiler (unless of course you explicitly cast it back to `object` or similar).

Comment: Will that allow me to pass the result as a typed param?

Comment: @StuartHemming would need more context; see my comment (in reply to yours) on the question